# Why is Yarn vue app is taking very long to build and compile?

Tags: vue.js, sass, compilation

I have a vue, tailwind, javascript based app. I am using yarn. For other users ideal time to build for this is 2-5 min, for each compile its 1-2 sec. What could possibly misconfigured in my setup :

versions :

- yarn : 1.22.19
- node : 12.16.1

```
package.json :
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
    "@headlessui/vue": "^1.7.13",
    "@mailupinc/bee-plugin": "1.2.0",
    "@tailwindcss/ui": "^0.6.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.18.1",
    "buefy": "^0.8.15",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "element-tiptap": "^1.26.2",
    "element-ui": "^2.15.1",
    "firebase": "^7.14.0",
    "invert-color": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "postcss-cli": "^7.1.0",
    "sass": "1.22.10",
    "sass-loader": "7.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.2.0",
    "tiptap": "^1.30.0",
    "tiptap-extensions": "^1.33.2",
    "vee-validate": "2.2.15",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-apexcharts": "^1.5.3",
    "vue-color": "^2.7.1",
    "vue-cute-timeline": "^1.2.8",
    "vue-intercom": "^1.0.14",
    "vue-query-builder": "^0.8.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.5",
    "vuex": "^3.1.3"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.3",
    "opn": "^5.1.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "prismjs": "^1.23.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.4",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

For this setup, my build time is around 40min, and each compile take around 2min.

Tried different versions of sass, sass-loader, didn't see any change.

Comment: The question is not constructive, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Yarn affects absolutely nothing in this case. Your setup and project matter on the other hand , but they are unknown. At least try to post the rest of package.json and whatever else configs that are specific to your build tool. If you don't use a fast ssd then that's the primary thing that needs to be improved, you won't get a satisfiable build time without it